# Why some of the Wordpress Urls take time to return html using the REST endpoint?

Tags: javascript, node.js, wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

Below is the Code I was hitting Asynchronously using Promises in NodeJS and I was hitting 275 urls to get their HTML if they are Wordpress urls.

But In 275 urls some urls took 33 seconds and gradually decreasing to 1 second.
Also 6 urls took more than 2 minutes, I had a 2 minutes timer set on the urls response.

What is the issue?
Is their anyone faced the same problem?

```
async function scrapeFromWordpress(url){
  const s = Date.now();
  let [domain] = url.match(/^(?:http:\/\/|www\.|https:\/\/)([^\/]+)/g);
  let [slug] = url.match(/[^/]+(?=\/$|$)/g);
  if(slug){
    slug = slug.split(".")[0];
  }
  let link = `${domain}/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?slug=${slug}`;
  try{
    const res = await axios({url: link,method: 'GET',headers: {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/38.0.2125.111 Safari/537.36'}
  });
    console.log("WORDPRESS")
    let response = [];
    if(res && res.data && Array.isArray(res.data) && res.data.length && res.data[0].content && res.data[0].content.rendered){
      console.log("Wordpress response ", url );
      response =  [res.data[0].content.rendered]
      return {url,wordpress_url:link,wordpressTimeTaken:parseFloat(Date.now()-s)/1000,status:true}
    }else{
      console.log("Non data found on wordpress")
      return {url,wordpress_url:link,wordpressTimeTaken:parseFloat(Date.now()-s)/1000,status:"No Data Found"}
    }
    return response;
  }catch(err){
    return  {url,wordpress_url:link,wordpressTimeTaken:parseFloat(Date.now()-s)/1000,status:"No Data Found", error:err.message};
  }
}
```

According to me,
`Urls should be processed in less than a 10 seconds. What are your thoughts?`

Comment: *"Urls should be processed in less than a 10 seconds"* - whoa, your internet is sure blazing fast. it really depends on the site and your internet no? assuming your internet is instantaneous, the only thing left is how much time each site needed to spool up.

Comment: Many factors govern how fast a site responds to a request. Unless the site is yours, none of those factors are within your control.  If you send many concurrent requests to a single site, it may have trouble keeping up and enqueue some requests. Some large WordPress hosting services offer rate-limiting reverse proxy servers to prevent them from being overwhelmed by scrapers like yours. Other WordPress sites use slow budget hosting services. Few web sites of any description (other than commercial API services) make guarantees about API responsiveness.